# how to specify a wmv output ffmpeg for example?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to transcode a single vob for a dvd player format, not to Rip! here's Vobl Trailing options were found on the commandline.

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : stereo
Input #0, mpeg, from 'concat:VTS_01_0.VOB':
Duration: 00:00:47.32, start: 0.277311, bitrate: 63386 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, fcc/bt470bg/bt470bg, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 6232 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:2[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
Stream #0:3[0xa0]: Audio: pcm_dvd, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s

At least one output file must be specified  ok?
```

Here I tried;

```
ffmpeg -i .vob -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf yadif -c:a copy"  okapA? All what I should want is here thanks!
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the desired output file name ? what is `okapA` ?

Comment: How about: `ffmpeg -i input.vob -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf yadif -c:a copy output.wmv`  And if the audio codec is incompatible: `ffmpeg -i input.vob -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf yadif -c:a aac output.wmv`

Comment: the ans, from ffmpeg is; Read only file system! OKapa/ my brothersss?/

Answer (score -1):

the my question I think don't have solutions/ I don't want to rip a DVD!but I finally found solutions OkapA? First I copied/saver on documents! After I output for the wmv [ ffmpeg commandeered the ending!the ffmpeg doesn’t rip nothing thanks dear/;

Comment: That’s good game “

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: All solving well weren’